# Show one $\sigma$-algebra is strictly contained in the other, given that $f$ is measurable on one of them

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a function. Let $X$ be a set and let ($Y$, $\mathcal{F}$) be a measurable space.  If we let $$\mathcal{T}=\{f^{-1}(F):F\in\mathcal{F}\}$$ and say that $\mathcal{B}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$ such that $f$ is ($\mathcal{B,F}$)-measurable, then show that $\mathcal{T}\subset\mathcal{B}$.

My attempt: Since $f$ is ($\mathcal{B,F}$)-measurable, we know that for any $F\in\mathcal{F}$, $f^{-1}(F)\in\mathcal{B}$. Since all elements of $\mathcal{T}$ are of this form, $\mathcal{T}\subset\mathcal{B}$. Since we need to show $\mathcal{T}$ is strictly contained in $\mathcal{B}$, it remains to show that $\mathcal{T}\neq\mathcal{B}$. This is where I struggle.

Comment: I don't know if you found this in a book, but usually $\subset$ does not mean 'strict subset'. Most authors use $\subset$ the same as $\subseteq$

Answer (score 3):

In general, $\mathcal{T}$ is not strictly contained in $\mathcal{B}$.

Just consider $X=Y$ and the identity mapping $f(x)=x$. Then $f$ is $(\mathcal{B},\mathcal{F})$-measurable if, and only if, $\mathcal{B} \supseteq \mathcal{F}$; in particular $f$ is $(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{F})$-measurable. Moreover, it follows straight from the definition that $\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{F}$ which is obviously not strictly contained in $\mathcal{F}$.